# I have a circuitikz that on Ubuntu 20.04 is correct but on 22.04 comes up garbled

Tags: circuitikz

I have the following `circuitikz` code

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\resizebox{250pt}{100pt}{
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) [vsource,l=$0V$,xshift=10pt] to [short] (6.5,0);
 \draw (1,0) to [sV, o-o, l=$Vin$] (1,3) % White noise source 
        to [short] +(0,1)
        to [short] +(1,0)
    to [european resistor,l=$R_1$] +(0,-2)
    to [european potentiometer,l=$R_{SPI2}$] +(0,-1)
    to [short] +(0,-1)
    ;
    % wiper R_{SPI2}
    \draw (2.6,2.3) to [short,-o] (2.6,1.5);
       \draw (3.5,4) to [C,l=$C$] (3.5,2.3)
    to [short] (3.5,3)
    ;

    \draw (5,4) to [short] +(0,-0.3)
     to [european potentiometer,l=$R_{SPI1}$] +(0,-1);
    \draw (5,2.6) to [short] (5,2.3);
    %wiper R_{SPI1}
    \draw (5.5,4) to [short,-o] (5.5,3.22);
    \draw (2,4) to [short] (3.5,4);

  \node[draw,circle,blue] (A) at (9,2.3) {$FFT2$};
   \draw [short,o-,blue] (8,2.3) to [short,-o] (2.0,2.3);
   \node[draw,circle,blue] (A) at (9,4) {$FFT1$};
   \draw [short,o-,blue] (8,4) to [short] (3.0,4.0)
    %to [short,-o] (15.0,3.0);
   ;

 \end{circuitikz}
 } % resize box
 \caption{
Blah blah blah impedance.
}
\label{fig:tds_wl_detector}
\end{figure}
```

On Ubuntu 22.04 installation it gives

[image]

On the older 20.04 Ubuntu it (seemingly correctly) gives

[image]

Am I doing something undefined using `circuitikz`?
It seems very strange they render differently.

Comment: I can't check right now, no PC at hand, but I'll try later or tomorrow. Anyway, even the "correct one" is garbled (admittedly less so); you have leads into the components because you have no sufficient space for them. And it seems you are using absolute coordinate for everything... Do you have any error? Undefined nodes maybe?

Comment: How do you load the packages? You should better submit a complete document, adding the class and loading the packages, so we can reproduce more accurately the problem.

Comment: Hmm... I rolled back to version 0.8.3 and it still compile badly. So I am at a loss why it did work before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with the first line:

```
 \draw (0,0) [vsource,l=$0V$,xshift=10pt] to [short] (6.5,0);
```

is incorrect syntax, and was never supported, so the behavior is undefined. The path-style element have to be specified *inside* a to command, so the syntax is:

```
\draw (coordinate 1) to[...whatever...] (coordinate 2);
```

...and effectively, you do not have the `vsource` labeled $0V$ anywhere. I do not know what your intention was, so I'll just guess it.

Then, I think you got the relative `+()` style coordinates wrong. They specify a relative coordinate, yes, but they do not move the current point...  I think you meant the `++()` syntax.

Finally, you can't guess distances as you are doing; you must learn to use orthogonal and named coordinates. For example, to connect to the wiper, you give a name to the potentiometer, and then you can use the `...name.wiper` anchor. For example:

```
\draw (2.6,2.3) to [short,-o] (2.6, 2.3 |- rspi2.wiper) -- (rspi2.wiper);
```

means: start from `(2.6,2.3)`; then go with a `short` element to the point which has the vertical position of `(2.6,2.3)` and the horizontal of the coordinate `(rspi2.wiper)`, adding a pole; and then continue to `(rspi2.wiper)` which is *exactly* the wiper position.

Moreover, in general, with the default size, a resistor does not fit in 1cm; I didn't want to change the coordinates, so I reduced the size of bipoles by 40% approx  with `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}`.

This is the minimum change to make your circuit compile correctly, but it's still quite poorly written. I'll try to add a better version later.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
    \draw (0,0) to[vsource,l=$0V$] (6.5,0);
    \draw (1,0) to [sV, o-o, l=$Vin$] (1,4) % White noise source 
        to [short] ++(1,0)
        to [european resistor,l=$R_1$] ++(0,-2)
        to [european potentiometer,l_=$R_{SPI2}$, name=rspi2] ++(0,-1)
        to [short] ++(0,-1)
        ;
    % wiper R_{SPI2}
    \draw (2.6,2.3) to [short,-o] (2.6, 2.3 |- rspi2.wiper) -- (rspi2.wiper);
    \draw (3.5,4) to [C,l=$C$] (3.5,2.3) 
        to [short] (3.5,3)
        ;

    \draw (5,4) to [short] ++(0,-0.3)
        to [european potentiometer,l=$R_{SPI1}$, name=rspi1] ++(0,-1.3);
    \draw (5,2.6) to [short] (5,2.3);
    %wiper R_{SPI1}
    \draw (5.5,4) to [short,-o] (5.5, 4 |- rspi1.wiper) -- (rspi1.wiper);
    \draw (2,4) to [short] (3.5,4);

    \node[draw,circle,blue] (A) at (9,2.3) {$FFT2$};
    % the following is wrong too
    \draw [short,o-,blue] (8,2.3) to [short,-o] (2.0,2.3);
    \node[draw,circle,blue] (A) at (9,4) {$FFT1$};
    % and this
    \draw [short,o-,blue] (8,4) to [short] (3.0,4.0)
        %to [short,-o] (15.0,3.0);
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally... if you need to rescale the circuit, do not do that with different x and y scales... it becomes really ugly. If you want to scale down everything, maintaining the proportions, use `scale=0.8, transform shape` in your picture options.

The way I would draw the circuit is this one, for example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) to[vsource,l=\SI{0}{V}] ++(7,0);
    % you could use the noise-style generators too, but let's just fill it
    \draw (1,0) to [sV, l=$V_{\mathit{in}}$, fill=gray] ++(0,4)
        to [short] ++(2,0) coordinate(top r1) % this will name the position as (top r1)
        to [european resistor,l=$R_1$] ++(0,-2) coordinate(bot r1)
        to [european potentiometer,l_=$R_{\mathit{SPI}2}$, name=rspi2] ++(0,-2)
        -- (0,0 -| top r1) % orthogonal coordinate, no guessing!
        ;
    \draw [blue] (bot r1) to[short, -o] ++(6,0) coordinate(fft2);
    \draw [blue] (top r1) to[short, -o] ++(6,0) coordinate(fft1);

    \draw (bot r1) ++(1,0) |- (rspi2.wiper);
    \draw (top r1) ++(2,0) coordinate(tmp) to [C,l_=$C$] (tmp|-bot r1);

    \draw (top r1) ++(4,0) coordinate(tmp)
        to [european potentiometer,l_=$R_{\mathit{SPI}1}$, name=rspi1] (tmp|-bot r1);
    \draw (top r1) ++(5,0) |- (rspi1.wiper);

    \node[draw,circle,blue, right=0.5cm] at(fft2) {\textit{FFT2}};
    \node[draw,circle,blue, right=0.5cm] at(fft1) {\textit{FFT1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Robin thanks, but please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers